# Dynamically inserting nodes into a graph, with different ranges

Tags: c#, graph, graph-theory, theory

If I have a graph of nodes, each with a position and range. I want to be able to insert nodes into my graph at any position and connect nodes within range. This would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
void InsertIntoGraph(newNode)
{
    // get all nodes within the range of the new node
    var nodes = findNodesInRange(newNode.position, newNode.range);

    // iterate over each node found
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        // do some magic to connect the nodes together.
        graph.connect(newNode, node);
    }
}
```

This looks fine, but can cause an issue with nodes with different ranges. Take the following image:

[image: graph]

If inserted into the graph in alphabetical order, an issue arises. A,B and C all have the same range.

- A is added, nothing in range
- B is added, A is within range - so B connects to A.
- C is added, B is within range, so C connects to B.
- D is added (has range = 8), nothing is within range.
- E is added (has range = 4 again), nothing is within range.

When E is added, because we are doing something along the lines of `findNodesInRange(newNode.position, newNode.range);` we are using the range of the node we are adding. So although E is within range of D (as D has a much larger range), we don't check that and we miss connections.

I'm trying to avoid having to check every node in the graph every time a node is created. My question is whether or not there is a smarter way of performing this task?

I have considered using some sort of spatial mapping to only check nodes within a "chunk", but that won't help if the range is larger than a chunk.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: The signature should be in the lines of `findNodesInRange(newNode, nodes)` and the method should return the nodes for which the distance to `newNode` is smaller than the _largest_ of both ranges. Then you need to add the connections based on each node's own range for all newNode - node pairs.

Comment: @Funk isn't that just processing the entire graph again every time you add a new node? As I said, I know that's a solution, but it's not really optimal.

Comment: You're already checking the entire graph, how else would you know which nodes are within range? You just need to use the largest range for each check. For the returned nodes you can add a connection to the largest range immediately and an additional check will tell if you can do the same for the smaller one.